# T-SQL, select data if first condition is true otherwise get the latest from second column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    SomeNumber  INT,
    Tag     VARCHAR(1),
    SomeDate Datetime
)
INSERT  INTO @T
(
    SomeNumber,
    Tag,
    SomeDate
)
VALUES
(1, 'A', NULL),
(2, 'A', NULL),
(2, 'B', '2018-11-04'),
(2, 'B', '2018-11-08'),
(2, 'B', '2018-11-09')
```

I wish to select the data from for an @T if tag is 'A' or the row with the same SomeNumber and latest date:

for example for SomeNumber 2, if Tag = 'A' then return:
(2, 'A', NULL)
and if tow with tag 'A' does not exist then return:
(2, 'B', '2018-11-09')

For the second condition I was thinking to use row_number over partition by SomeNumber order by SomeDate DESC and then get rowNumber 1.

But, how do I check if the first condition is true or get the latest from second column (SomeDate) fro the same SomeNumber?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your request to select a Tag when there is no match for the one you look up is nondeterministic: the latest date can belong to multiple Tags, so either you need to pick the smallest/largest (or whatever aggregation), or accept multiple results. E.g. when there is also data like:
(2, 'C', '2018-11-09').

This query solves your problem, notice that I used the smallest Tag when there is no match for the one you look up and also marked where to modify the query not to do aggregation and occasionally return multiple rows:

```
DECLARE @SomeNumber INT = 2, @Tag as VARCHAR(1) = 'A'

DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    SomeNumber  INT,
    Tag     VARCHAR(1),
    SomeDate Datetime
)
INSERT  INTO @T
(
    SomeNumber,
    Tag,
    SomeDate
)
VALUES
(1, 'A', NULL),
(2, 'A', NULL),
(2, 'B', '2018-11-04'),
(2, 'B', '2018-11-08'),
(2, 'B', '2018-11-09'),
(2, 'C', '2018-11-09')

DECLARE @Result TABLE
(
    SomeNumber  INT,
    Tag     VARCHAR(1),
    SomeDate Datetime
)

INSERT @Result
SELECT SomeNumber, Tag, MAX (SomeDate) as LatestDate
FROM @T
WHERE SomeNumber = @SomeNumber and Tag = @Tag
GROUP BY SomeNumber, Tag

-- SELECT * FROM @Result

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT @Result
    SELECT
        TagNotFound.SomeNumber
        ,MIN (T.Tag) as Tag -- use Tag only if you want all Tags for latest date
        ,TagNotFound.LatestDate
    FROM (
        SELECT SomeNumber, MAX (SomeDate) as LatestDate
        FROM @T
        WHERE SomeNumber = @SomeNumber
        GROUP BY SomeNumber
        ) as TagNotFound
    INNER JOIN @T as T
        on T.SomeNumber = TagNotFound.SomeNumber and T.SomeDate = TagNotFound.LatestDate
    GROUP BY TagNotFound.SomeNumber, TagNotFound.LatestDate -- comment this line out if you remove aggregate for Tag
END

SELECT * FROM @Result
```

I didn't want to put the whole thing into one SELECT to avoid running the second more complicated construct when there is matching Tag.

Results for different Tags:
For 'A' it gives 2, 'A', NULL
For 'B' it gives 2, 'B', '2018-11-09'
For 'C' it gives 2, 'C', '2018-11-09'
For 'D' it gives 2, 'B', '2018-11-09' and gives 2 rows when aggregation is commented out:
2, 'B', '2018-11-09'
2, 'C', '2018-11-09'

Comment: Thanks David. I forgot to mention that it the SomeDate can not be the same within the same SomeNumber even if the tag changes. For example we can not have (2, 'C', '2018-11-09'). And the query should return the latest (newest SomeDate) within same SomeNumber regardless of the tag, if for example (2, 'A', NULL) does not exist. Does this make the query simpler?

Comment: Also, in addition to my comment above, would it be possible to not using table @Result and use some combinations of CTE ?
And, there can be many other SomeNumber, Tag and SomeDate in the table. I wish to return all the results for each SomeNumber. But 'A' has NULL as SomeDate always.

Comment: Based on what you are saying you can re-write the query, you don't need to wait for me. The answer addresses the question not the comment section. More info at the beginning makes answers closer to solving your problem. Use the query samples and run tests with different modifications on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY SomeNumber ORDER BY Tag,SomeDate) As rn
FROM @T) AS r
WHERE r.rn=1
```

Comment: For the first case (Tag = 'A', Number = 2) your query will return 2 rows which is not what OP want, and if there is not it will return B and A.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
SELECT SomeNumber,
       Tag,
       MAX(SomeDate) SomeDate
FROM @T
WHERE SomeNumber = 2 AND Tag = 
     (CASE 
          WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @T WHERE Tag = 'A' AND SomeNumber = 2) THEN 'A'
          WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @T WHERE Tag = 'B' AND SomeNumber = 2) THEN 'B'       
     END)
GROUP BY SomeNumber, Tag;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df95070ac7c3451aed90690c2e4af7b5)**

Comment: Thanks Sami. Please have a look at the comment I put for David.
I do not wish to have the SomeNumber hard coded to 2, as there can be many other SomeNumber(s).